# MYSQL Выбрать данные из поля JSON с цифровым ключём

Tags: mysql, json

MySQL 5.7

Есть таблица:

```
INSERT INTO `tj10` (`id`, `a`) 
VALUES (1, '{"3": 10, "8": 17}'),
(2, '{"3": 11, "5": 55, "0": 44}'),
(3, '{"3": 12, "7": 55, "5": 57, "0": 44}');
```

Как выбрать из таблицы все записи у которых есть ключ "5" в столбце "a"?

Как извлечь значение ключа "5" в столбце "a"?

Ключи могут стоять в разном порядке.

`a->'$.5'` выдает ошибку, а `a->"$[5]"` берет значение 6-го ключа по порядку

Comment: Выбрать все записи можно добавив в условие WHERE a LIKE '%"5": %', но это не совсем правильное решение.